# How to extend from VTextField?

Tags: vuejs2, components, extends, vuetify.js

i wan to set default values to the VTextField props, to achieve this i extended from it and overwrite some of the default props:

```
<script>
import VTextField from 'vuetify/es5/components/VTextField';
const theme_config = require('@/theme/config.json');
export default {
    name: 'my-text-field',
    extends: VTextField,
    props: theme_config.components.default_input,
};
</script>
```

the config.json look like this:

```
{
    "components": {
        "default_input":{
            "color": {
                "default": "secondary"
            },
            "outline": {
                "default": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the parent component that use my-text-field look like this:

```
<template>
    <my-text-field 
        type="text" 
        append-icon="person"
    >
    </my-text-field>
</template>
```

but when vue render, it change my-text-fiel by v-text-field:

[image: captured from VueDevTools]

this is not the first time that i extends a Vuetify's component , it worck perfectly whit a button, i have not idea whats hapening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the first time that I have to answer my own questions but I did because maybe there are other peoples here that have the same problem.

The problem whit v-text-field component is that it was designed for the use of multiline and single line, to acquire this they put a wrapper on the index, but this will become obsolete in the new Vuetify2 for that reason they have two components now that you can use perfectly by they own. That’s why I changed the original text input index.js to one of my own, who import an VTextInput like the other components on vuetify.

this is my index.js

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.VTextField = undefined;

var _VTextField = require('./VTextField');

var _VTextField2 = _interopRequireDefault(_VTextField);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

exports.VTextField = _VTextField2.default;
exports.default = _VTextField2.default;
```

This is not a fancy solution, but maybe it help to others to solve the problem.